# How to create timestamp?

Tags: excel, vba

For a new template a log file is needed. In this log file, a timestamp is created once an individual has signed off a specific item.

This is done by the following:

```vb
Function Timestamp(Reference As Range)
    
If Reference.Value <> "" Then    
    Timestamp = Format(DateTime.Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")  
Else    
    Timestamp = ""
End If

End Function
```

I've used the function type, as this code needs to run on several sheets.

It can happen that a certain sheets need to be copied, which triggers this macro to run again and to adjust the previous timestamps which therefore do not correspond to the time it was signed off.

I'm looking for a way to adjust this code to not run again once a sheet is copied.

I've tried the additional code, however it does not work properly.

```vb
Function Copyasvalue(Reference As Range)
    
If Reference.Value <> "" Then
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
Else
    Copyasvalue = ""
End If
    
End Function
```

Comment: ***which triggers this macro to run again***, How? Is it a UDF?

Comment: As far as I know it is a UDF.

Comment: Well, if it is a UDF the timestamp shows the time when the last calculation run in this cell. So it will renew whenever someone forces Excel to recalculate. If that is not what you expect please provide a better description of what you actually were trying to accomplish. Can you provide a small data example and the explanation when the timestamp should be updated?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the unclear question. What I'm trying to accomplish is as follows:
Each sheet in this Excel file needs to be filled in and signed off by the responsible manager. Once the Manager signs off the sheet by filling in his/her name, a timestamp is created in the cell below by the UDF. 

However, sometimes it can happen that a sheet needs to be copied (within the file). In the current situation, the timestamp cell is recalculated and therefore the timestamp is updated. The timestamp should not be updated in that situation.

Comment: @dijkie Is the problem solved or does none of the answers work?

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved! Thanks for all your support.

Comment: @dijkie In that case you should accept the answer that helped you. This makes the question solved and can be used for future reference if someone has the same problem. You accept a answer by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Workbook_SheetChange() to do what you want.

In Workbook object of the vba project add this function:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        ' If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then  'if you want to be able to copy paste as @Pᴇʜ explains in comments below
        If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then 'cell where name is entered. if only entered by typeing
        Range("A1").Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss") 'cell where date time should be etered
    end if
End Sub
```

with the variable `sh` you can limit it to only run in some sheets.
`if not sh.name = "Don't run on this sheet" then` to make sure it does not run on that sheet.

The datetime will not change unless you change the "name cell".

Comment: Replace `If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then` with `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then` otherwise your code will not work if someone copies a range of data over B1. • If the code should apply to multiple sheets or all sheets you might want to have a look into the `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` that is triggered on every sheet change so you don't have to copy over the code (avoid code repetition).

Comment: Did not know about workbook sheetchange. Thanks! But if you place the code at the first sheet then it will be copied when you copy a sheet. No manual copying is needed. (But your way is off course better).

Comment: Yes, it will copy the code and if you need to change it you will need to change it in each sheet wich can be a lot of fun. So you should at least put the code in a module and just call the module procedure form your event. Or if you use the `Workbook_SheetChange` event you need only to change only one code for all sheets too. Avoiding repeating code is always a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

So after what I understand:

You can call a Sub like: `Call timeStamp`

```
Private Sub timeStamp()
Dim time As String

time = Format(now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
Debug.Print time
MsgBox time
Range(A1).Value = time

End Sub
```